# How can I CORRECTLY append map array to firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add Map<> data to my firestore database with code :

```
Map<String, Object> prop = {
  'read' : true,
  'vote_left' : false,
  'vote_right' : false,
};
Map<String, Object> attended_topic =
{
  received_id:prop
};

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userinfo').doc(user_now!.uid)
    .update({"attended_topic": FieldValue.arrayUnion([attended_topic])});
```

What I expected is this.

```
attended_topic
  topicId_0
    read : true 
    vote_left : false
    vote_right : false
```

But I got something unexpected.

```
attended_topic
  0
    topicId_0
      read : true 
      vote_left : false
      vote_right : false
```

I never expected that new category '0' appearing and donot know why. Since the atabase has other properties so I thought using `update()` rather than `set()` is adequate. Please somebody tell my why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)
`FieldValue.arrayUnion` adds elements to an array but only elements not already present.

So `{"a": FieldValue.arrayUnion([b])}` adds `b` variable to the `Array` `a`.

To solve your problem, just remove `FieldValue` as shown below.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('userinfo')
    .doc(user_now!.uid)
    .set({"attended_topic": attended_topic}, SetOptions(merge: true));
// use set method to add new data (not update)
// or

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userinfo').doc(user_now!.uid).set(
  {
    'attended_topic': {
      received_id: {
        'read': true,
        'vote_left': false,
        'vote_right': false,
      }
    }
  },
  SetOptions(merge: true),
);
```

Comment: It seems that `set()` removes all other data in the target doc. Can you please suggest me some supplementary ?

Comment: Simply use `SetOptions(merge: true)`. I will update my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem referring Peter's solution and changing it slightly.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userinfo').doc(user_now!.uid)
    .set({"attended_topic": attended_topic}, SetOptions(merge: true));
```